# How do you communicate between firebase service worker and Vue/Vuex web app

Tags: vue.js, vuex, service-worker

We are running a Vue application that has a firebase service worker running "next" to it.
The service worker has been initiated as such:

```
// main.js

import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/messaging'

...

const firebase_config = {
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID',
  storageBucket: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_MESSAGING_SEND_ID'
}
console.log('firebase', firebase)

new Vue({ 
...
```

In the firebase-messaging-sw.js file (in the public directory) we handle the data message as such:

```
// firebase-messaging-sw.js

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.2/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.2/firebase-messaging.js')

// for some reason it requires this again
const firebase_config = {
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID',
  storageBucket: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_MESSAGING_SEND_ID'
  appId: 'YOUR_APPID'
}
firebase.initializeApp(firebase_config)

const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // I want to access the vue or vuex component here
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  return true
}
```

How do you make a call back to the vue/vuex store, or access one of the DOM elements, if it is there?

**EDIT**

Here is some more detail:

It seems that the way you communicate from the service worker to the main app it with the postMessage() function.
The postMessange() function needs a client object that can be found by the fetch event and a fetch event is triggered when you access a url.
Unfortunately vue does not seem to fetch url's as it is a singe page app therefore you cant get a client therefore you can't use it to run a postMessage() (unless I got that wrong, all help is appreciated)

Here is the code I got for posting a message on fetch event:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async function() {
      // Exit early if we don't have access to the client.
      // Eg, if it's cross-origin.
      if (!event.clientId) return

      // Get the client.
      const client = await clients.get(event.clientId)
      // Exit early if we don't get the client.
      // Eg, if it closed.
      if (!client) return

      // Send a message to the client.
      client.postMessage({
        msg: 'Hey I just got a fetch from you!',
        url: event.request.url
      })
    })()
  )
})
```

Comment: I would recommend storing your Firebase credentials (and any api keys) in a .env file, rather than directly in the Javascript. Otherwise, you expose your api keys to the public.

Comment: @Tanner storing them in a .env does not hide them from the public once the code gets "packed" for the web. They will just as well reside in the code.

It would be best to authenticate first, then storing the credentials in a local storage (or so) and then using these sockets in your request so that the only thing your code will be doing is receiving tokens and sending user input to the api to verify their credentials.

Comment: @hugo-van-schalkwyk Have you got any solution ? I am also facing same issue. I am using vuex

Comment: @Mallikarjun we decided to not use the Firebase option and rather to have a poling mechanism on the site as the user use it. The firebase option required the user to agree on push notifications that we were unsure the user would know to agree on.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having `messaging.onBackgroundMessage` resides in the sw file which located in `public` folder, I am wondering how do I ping my Vue components when a background notification arrives in the sw file callback, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In React (yes I know this is Vue, hold your horses) handling asynchronous events is usually done using a middleware. Redux-saga is one of these middlewares and it supports Event channels which give you a way to tie your external event logic (e.g. your firebase event) to your internal store using puts or calls to your vuex actions.

Redux-saga is not tied to redux (as it seems) and there are several adapters that support this (vuex-redux-saga, vuex-nia or vuex-coolstory). There are some more listed here: https://yarnpkg.com/?q=vuex%20saga&p=1

Please be wary that I personally did not use any of these libraries, though I have come to love the Saga middleware approach.

Comment: From what I can see in the documentation, these libraries makes it easier to communicate with asynchronous functions inside a page. My problem is that I want to communicate between a service worker and a functions running on a page. I am new to all this so I might be missing something.

Comment: Take a look at event channels (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html). You can wrap your backgroundMessageHandler in a channel and then "emit" this to your vuex actions.